# How do I bind Html.DevExtreme().LookupFor list to model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, devextreme

I am using DevExtreme.LookupFor to show dropdown list and select an object element to my model
But always I got null to model property..

uisng asp.net core

This is my dropdownlist :

```
<div class="form-inline">
    <label asp-for="Prop" class="control-label"></label>

    <div class="form-inline formGroup">
        @(Html.DevExtreme().LookupFor(m => m.Prop)
                           .DataSource(d => d.RemoteController()
                           .LoadUrl("/looks/Getlist"))
                           .DisplayExpr("Description")
                           .Width("100%")
                           .Value(Model.Prop)
     )
    </div>
    <span asp-validation-for="Prop" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

This is my mode :

```
@model Main.Vals.Code.Models.PropModule
```

This is the relevant important part for my question :

```
public class PropModule
{
    // List
    [Display(Name = "PARAMS")]
    public Prop Prop { get; set; }

}
```

When Im using action I go to

```
<form class="formEntity" asp-controller="Cont" asp-action="Action">
```

In this action When I look on Modle.Prop Its show null also when I chose a variable

```
public IActionResult Action(PropModule Modle)
{
     ....  
}
```

[image]

UI Picture of the dropdown list for example :

[image]

[image]

I

What I do wrong?   Tell me if I miss any important information

Comment: 'devexpress' and 'devextreme' are two totally separate frameworks...decide which one you want to use first

Comment: I think It is devextreme     DevExtreme.AspNet.Mvc.HtmlHelperExtensions.DevExtreme

form #region Assembly DevExtreme.AspNet.Core, Version=19.2.12.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a
// .... \DevExtreme.AspNet.Core.dll
#endregion

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need to add a

`.ValueExpr("Whatever-your-key-is")`

to the lookup, and this is what gets passed to the code-behind, so this should look like

```
public IActionResult Action(int key)
{
     // lookup prop depending on key
}
```

The key has to be something that can be serialized (e.g. int, string, guid, etc.)

cheers